# Java lambda - modify value in forEach loop

Tags: java, lambda, foreach

I was trying to achieve something like this using lambdas. However, "i" has to be final.

```
int i = 1;
for (Object obj : list) {
 if (something) {
  i++;
 }
}
```

**edit:**

But what if I wanted to add, let's say, a value that is different from object to object?

```
int i = 1;
for (Object obj : list) {
   if (something) {
      otherMethod(i);
      i += obj.getValue();
   }
}
```

Comment: short answer is, if you are thinking how to combine functional style with mutation, it's already a fatal starting point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this instead:

```
int i = 1 + (int)list.stream().filter(something).count();
```

where `something` is the criteria to `filter`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! But what if I wanted to add, let's say, a value that is different from object to object?

Comment: Then you can use the map intermediate operation.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ? To extract some type of value from each object ? And sum it  or?

Comment: Yea, get a Value from every object in a list and sum it - to be exact, I want to loop through the list, and add to the sume for every entry, after calling another method with the current sum. Sorry for the bad original Question - I edited it.

Comment: you should avoid side effects when working with streams. can you show the definition of `otherMethod` and the type returned from `getValue`.

Comment: getValue will return a double, but it doesn't matter if I change "i" to double. otherMethod needs getName (String) and i.

Comment: @memelord if `otherMethod` needs `String` then why are you passing `int`? please show the `otherMethod` definition so I can best understand why you insist on declaring `i` outside the loop.

Comment: It needs both, a String and the int. To be exact, it renders a String at a specific position. However, the Strings have a different height, so in order to render all the strings of the objects under the one before, I have to add the heights of the Strings rendered before to the current ypos/i in my example

Answer (score 1):

As in the first answer written to count the elements, you first filter, then reduce (with `count()`).

```
list.stream().filter(obj -> something).count();
```

But if do not want to count the items, but use instead some value depending on the object, you should first map the stream to the intermediate values, and reduce them with e.g. `sum`.

```
list.stream()
    .filter(obj -> something)
    .mapToInt(obj -> obj.getValue())
    .sum()
```

You should never modify anything while using streams. (`forEach` can be an exception).